# How to Initalize Tread Local Storage in C

Tags: multithreading, gcc, pthreads, thread-local

```
static __thread vars* ptr=NULL;
void thread_init(vars* new_vars){
    if(new_vars){
        ptr=new_vars
    }
    printf("%p",ptr);
}
```

__thread is GCC's extention

thread1 is one thread of main

thread1_child is child of thread1

call thread_init(a) in main             //ptr is a, not NULL

call thread_init(b) in thread1          //ptr is b, not NULL

call thread_init(NULL) in thread1_child //ptr is NULL,not b

how to dynamically initialize
(ptr of thread1 == ptr of thread1_child) ?

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? What behaviour do you get? What is the code ([mcve]) that you're running? The above is not a sufficient description. In any case, searching for `__threads_local` should turn up a few examples here and there. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What's `__threads_local`?  Do you mean `_Thread_local` (single leading underscore, capital 'T', no 's')?

Comment: Ok then, what's `__thread`?  There is a GCC keyword with that spelling, but it is not standard C nor part of pthreads, and you have not tagged GCC.